# Roots of an algebraic equation

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

Show that the equation 
$$1+x+\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{3}+ \cdots+\frac{x^n}{n} = 0$$ 
has no real root if $n$ is even and one real root if $n$ is odd.

Comment: Kindly help me to solve the problem.

Comment: I think one root is 1

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 3):

The derivative of the LHS is $$1+x+\cdots x^{n-1}=\begin{cases}x=1\to n,\\x\ne1\to\dfrac{x^n-1}{x-1}\end{cases}.$$

For odd $n$, the numerator only cancels at $x=1$, and the derivative remains positive (numerator and denominator keep the same sign). Hence the function has a single root.

For even $n$, the numerator also cancels at $x=-1$, and the function has an extremum there. But the value at the extremum is positive and it must be a minimum. Hence, no root.

Comment: @Servaes: of course, thanks !

Comment: Strange notation of piecewise function >.>